# Notions of groups acting on groups

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $S$, by means of $(g,s)\mapsto s^g$. If $S$ is itself also a group, then it is natural to impose the further condition that $(st)^g=s^gt^g$. This seems to be the standard notion of a group acting on a group, and the action of a group on itself by conjugation is a central example. But, denoting the group action of $G$ on $S$ by $(g,s)\mapsto g\cdot s$, what about the following natural condition instead: $g\cdot (st)=(g\cdot s) t$ ? The canonical action of a group on itself satisfying this condition. Is there a standard name for such an action? If so, a reference will be appreciated. If not, is there any compelling reason why this notion is not worthy ?

Comment: If $g.(st)=(g.s)t$, $g(t)=g(e)t$. Let $f(g)=g(e)$. Then $f:G->S$ is an homomorphim. So your group acts by left translation on this group $S$. Is this your question ?

Comment: There is the related notion of [G-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the very clear answer.

Comment: In the OP, I believe "the canonical action of a group on itself" means $g * s := gs$ (left multiplication). I initially assumed it was $g * s = gsg^{-1}$ (conjugation), but that satisfies $g * (st) = (g * s)t$ if and only if $g * t = t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to remove this from the unanswered section, we copy Thomas' comment that answered the OP's question:

If $g \cdot (st)=(g\cdot s)t$,$ g(t)=g(e)t$. Let $f(g)=g(e)$. Then $f: G \to S$ is an homomorphim. So your group acts by left translation on this group $S$. Is this your question?

Comment: I'm not sure if "left translation" is the right word, since $g * 1_S$ may vary for different $g \in G$. But yes, for a fixed, individual $g \in G$, $g * t = (g * 1_S) t$ for all $t \in S$, so $g$ acts on $S$ as left multiplication by $g * 1_S \in S$.